# How to excute a loop in tens, if 20 items the loop to run twice and so on

Tags: php

I'm looking for a solution to run the PHP loop into tens. This question is hard to phrase but I will try to keep it simple.

First, this is my code.

```
function custom_betcurry_s_in_s( $hey_stack, $needle ){
    return strpos( $hey_stack , $needle ) !== false; 
}

$data = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,22,23';

$array = explode( ',', $data );

$total = count( $array );

// how many tens do we have here
// the first one is from 0 to 9
// how many tens

$my_tens = $total / 10; 

$loops_parts = explode( '.', $my_tens );


$loops = $loops_parts[0]; 
$remainder = $loops_parts[1]; 

for( $i = 1; $i < ( (int) $loops + 1 ); $i++ ){
    //echo $i;
    //$start = $i
    // here section my $array into 10s
    // like this 
    // I'm stuck here
}
    
// Desired out put should be 
// first string = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
// second string = 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
// 3rd string 21, 22, 23
```

the idea is to run loops in 10s, if I have 40 items in my array then the loop should be executed 4 times with 4 strings if 60 then the loop to be executed 6 times with 6 strings, if 64, the loop to be executed 7 times, that is 6 times from 0 to 60 and 7th time from 61 to 64 and so on and so forth

Comment: Have a look at [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: FYI: The correct spelling is `$haystack`. It is not meant like "Hey, stack!". It is from the saying "finding a needle in a haystack." For example see [array_search manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: @DarkBee your solution has worked great. array_chunk will solve the issue